# Joke I don't get

Tags: american-english, jokes

So here the joke I be heard, but I don't get the meaning of it. Can anyone help me understand why is it the answer supposed to be funny?

> Q: What did the duck say when she bought lipstick?
>
> A: "Put it on my bill."

Comment: What research have you done?  Where have you looked? What part do you have trouble understanding? https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bill

Comment: The joke is a pun, a play on two distinct meanings of “bill”. One is the duck’s beak, its mouth, where the lipstick would be applied (where its lips would be if it had lips). The other meaning of “bill” is like “invoice” or “tab”, a listing of items purchased along with price, and a total cost to be paid. Since he’s buying the lipstick, the purchase would also be listed on this type of “bill”.

Comment: Asking for prior research is rather harsh if the OP doesn't know that it is a play on words, and what particular word has a double meaning. +1  because it is a nice joke.

Comment: "If your nose runs and your feet smell, you've been built upside-down." -- Spike Milligan

Comment: @mike , thanks Mike that means a lot , and trust I looked.